# MessageBeep not playing any sound

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to use the [`MessageBeep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API to play a sound, but no sound plays.

```
MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONASTERISK);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONHAND);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONQUESTION);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONSTOP);
MessageBeep(MB_ICONWARNING);
MessageBeep(MB_OK);
```

- Yes have speakers plugged in
- Yes the volume is turned up
- Yes i hear other MessageBeeps (UAC, Default, Error, etc)
- Yes i hear audio from other application ([what i'm listing to right now is irocnical](https://youtu.be/VbmOvLEqCmA))
- Windows 10.0.14393 64-bit
- Interactively connected (i.e. not through terminal services remote desktop session)
- the function (which returns a `BOOL`) returns `true`

  [image]
- Yes there is a *"Default"* sound set in the Sounds applet of the Control Panel

  [image]
- The **Beep** service is started (although the `Beep` function is not relevant here)
- Applications are not allowed to take exclusive control of my default (and only) sound device:

  [image]
- Windows does not *attempt* to play any sound; you can see no "output levels" in the Volume Mixer:

  [image]

What am I missing?

### Sample code to reproduce the problem

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    MessageBox(0, 'About to play sounds', 'TestApp', MB_OK);

     MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONASTERISK);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONHAND);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONQUESTION);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONSTOP);
     MessageBeep(MB_ICONWARNING);
     MessageBeep(MB_OK);
     MessageBeep($ffffffff);
    MessageBox(0, 'After playing sounds', 'TestApp', MB_OK);
end;
```

Tested on:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Windows 7 64-bit
- Windows 7 64-bit
- Delphi 5

  [image]
- Delphi 7

  [image]
- Delphi XE6

  [image]

### See Also

- [MSDN Forums: No sound from MessageBeep()](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb144952-d1c5-41c8-9a50-841b6fb4a538/no-sound-from-messagebeep?forum=vclanguage) ([archive](http://archive.is/pYbSs))

### Bonus Reading

- [Larry Osterman: What’s up with the Beep driver in Windows 7?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2010/01/04/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7/)

  The Windows `Beep` function was re-engineered starting with Windows 7 to no longer use the PC speaker, and now uses the default sound device.

Comment: Does it work for non-console application? Just curious. I have not try your code sample yet.

Comment: It is not very sane code.  It races through these MessageBeep() calls in a few microseconds and terminates the program.  No sound.  Sleep for a while to hear something.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara It does not work for any application. I found it when no sound would happen during a GUI button click. People are being quite distracted by the example - that also plays no code.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I can't reproduce the problem, whether it's with your console or GUI samples. Are you sure the issue is with MessageBeep and not your sound configuration itself? Do you get sounds from other apps such as Explorer? (You should look at the docs for MessageBeep, btw; it accepts about half of the constants you're passing to it, and some of them are redundant because they're synonyms of each other. I'd remove all of the calls except $FFFFFFFF; if it works the others will.)

Comment: @KenWhite I get UAC, default, UAC insert and removal sounds. I assumed it must have been my PC; but i tried it on two co-worker machines. It's entirely possible their machines are also in an unsupported hardware configuration where: we can all hear sound, we can all hear other standard notification sounds, but MessageBeep doesn't work.

Comment: I can see you have 2 devices that can play sound. Did you check both devices? Maybe for some reason system sound are played on the device you're not listening for?

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this problem right now
first step:[image: first step]click on the task bar on the speaker icon 
go in options and you must toogle system sound.
Screenshoot are taken on windows 7 familly prenium french version but it may be nearly the same in newest versions.

[image: second step]